# Forcing an argument in a Clojure macro to get namespace-captured

Tags: macros, clojure, quoting

I am working on a Clojure macro to help build GridBagLayout-based JPanels. I can get Java classes in a defaults map inside the macro to namespace-qualify, but not those passed in as arguments. What magic combination of backquotes, quotes, tildas, or something else do I need?

```
(import [java.awt GridBagConstraints GridBagLayout Insets]
        [javax.swing JButton JPanel])

(defmacro make-constraints [gridx gridy & constraints]
  (let [defaults
        {:gridwidth 1 :gridheight 1 :weightx 0 :weighty 0
         :anchor 'GridBagConstraints/WEST :fill 'GridBagConstraints/NONE
         :insets `(Insets. 5 5 5 5) :ipadx 0 :ipady 0}

        values
        (assoc (merge defaults (apply hash-map constraints))
          :gridx gridx :gridy gridy)]
    `(GridBagConstraints. ~@(map (fn [value]
                                   (if
                                    (or
                                     (number? value)
                                     (string? value)
                                     (char? value)
                                     (true? value)
                                     (false? value)
                                     (nil? value))
                                    value
                                    `~value))
                                 (map values
                                      [:gridx :gridy :gridwidth :gridheight
                                       :weightx :weighty :anchor :fill
                                       :insets :ipadx :ipady])))))
```

When I use the `Insets` defined in the defaults map, it gets qualified (not "symbol-captured") as `(java.awt.Insets ...)`:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(make-constraints 0 0 :weightx 1))
(java.awt.GridBagConstraints.
 0 0 1 1 1 0
 GridBagConstraints/WEST GridBagConstraints/NONE
 (java.awt.Insets. 5 5 5 5) 0 0)
```

but when I pass it as an argument, it does not:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(make-constraints 1 1 :insets (Insets. 2 2 2 2)))
(java.awt.GridBagConstraints.
 1 1 1 1 0 0
 GridBagConstraints/WEST GridBagConstraints/NONE
 (Insets. 2 2 2 2) 0 0)
```

I'm not just trying to be a stickler. I am getting compiler errors that it cannot find a proper `GridBagConstraints` constructor.

Comment: If the client calling your macro has `Insets` imported in his namespace, your macro shouldn't need to qualify it for him (and it'd be a lot of work to do in general). If he doesn't have `Insets` imported, he's doing it wrong. It looks to me like those two should either both compile or both not compile, given that the user has the right `import`. Catering to users who don't have the right `import` will only lead to tears for all involved; if it's still broken could you provide more info?

Comment: Ralph, which Java version and which Clojure version are you using?  Both invocations of make-constraints, including the one where you passed an Insets, work for me.  I am using Clojure 1.2.0 and Sun Java 1.6.0_24.  See http://pastebin.com/kD5ccwvd.

Comment: As an aside, the `#`s on your locals is misleading. It implies they're being used as gensyms in the expansion context, when really they're just locals with a funny name used while the macro is running.

Comment: @amalloy: The `#`s come from a poor understanding of `gensym` on my part. After you mentioned it, I thought again and realized that the only symbols that I need to gensym are those *bound* in the *expansion* of my macro (none in this case). I updated the question.

Comment: @user100464: Java 6 build 26 on OsX, Clojure 1.2. Actually this macro is a simplification of a more complex macro that actually builds the whole JPanel. I may have inadvertently fixed my own problem when simplifying it. I'll look again at my original.

Comment: @ralph Is this still part of learning macro-fu? If not, I'd like to advice to reconsider the use of a macro here. Alone from the problem description of what your macro does, I don't see a single reason hinting at why this should be a macro. If possible, use a function. It will save you from all these tedious `gensym`, quoting and expanding business.

Comment: @ralph BTW, are you aware, that the `if` in the first `map` always returns `value`? The function is just the `identity`.

Comment: @kotarak: Yeah, still learning macros. I have posted my complete solution as the answer to this question. I actually believe the macro is easier to use than typing the full `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: @kotarak: ... and only took about 50 times longer to write :-).

Comment: @ralph Hehe. The speed-up comes asymptotically. ;)

Comment: @kotarak: Yeah. And now I have to move my asymptote to other problems in this application or I'll never finish it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I am using it in a Swing application that I am writing. It has already saved me many lines of code writing (for two different panels) and will be as fast as hand-written code.

```
(defmacro grid-bag-container [container & args]
  "Fill and return a java.awt.Container that uses the GridBagLayout.
  The macro defines a set of default constraints for the GridBagConstraints:
    :gridwidth 1
    :gridheight 1
    :weightx 0
    :weighty 0
    :anchor :WEST
    :fill :NONE
    :insets (Insets. 5 5 5 5)
    :ipadx 0
    :ipady 0
  These defaults can be overridden in the call to the macro in two way:
    - If the first argument is a hash-map of constraint names and values
      (e.g.: {:weightx 1}), these will override the defaults for the
      entire container.
    - Each individual item (see below) can override the global defaults
      and container defaults for itself.
  The constraints consist of constraint name (as a keyword with the same
  name as the GridBagConstraints field), and a value, which can also be
  a keyword, in which case the appropriate constant from GridBagConstraints
  will be substituted (e.g.: :NONE == GridBagConstraints.NONE), or the value
  can be an expression (e.g.: 0 or (Insets. 2 2 2 2)).
  Following the optional container default overrides hash-map are one or
  more row specification vectors. Each vector represents one row and
  increments gridy (starting from 0). Each vector contains one or more
  item vectors representing the individual components to be added to the
  container. Each item vector has the component as its first value,
  followed by zero or more constraint overrides as keyword-value pairs.
  (e.g.: [myButton :gridwidth 2 :weightx 1]). The values may be keywords
  and are expanded to GridBagConstraints constants as described above.
  Each item vector gets the next value of gridx (starting with 0) in that
  row.
  For example:
    (grid-bag-container panel
      {:insets (Insets. 1 1 1 1)}
      [[button :gridwidth 2 :weightx 1.0 :fill :HORIZONTAL]]
      [[check-box :gridwidth 2 :weightx 1.0 :anchor :CENTER]]
      [[arrive-label] [arrive-text-field :fill :HORIZONTAL]]
      [[depart-label] [depart-text-field :fill :HORIZONTAL]])
  will expand to the hand-written equivalent:
    (doto panel
      (.add button
        (GridBagConstraints. 0 0 2 1 1.0 0  ; gridx: 0 gridy: 1
                             GridBagConstraints/WEST
                             GridBagConstraints/HORIZONTAL
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
      (.add check-box
        (GridBagConstraints. 0 1 2 1 1.0 0  ; gridx: 0 gridy: 1
                             GridBagConstraints/CENTER
                             GridBagConstraints/NONE
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
      (.add arrive-label
        (GridBagConstraints. 0 2 1 1 0 0    ; gridx: 0 gridy: 2
                             GridBagConstraints/WEST
                             GridBagConstraints/NONE
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
      (.add arrive-text-field
        (GridBagConstraints. 1 2 1 1 0 0    ; gridx: 1 gridy: 2
                             GridBagConstraints/WEST
                             GridBagConstraints/HORIZONTAL
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
      (.add depart-label
        (GridBagConstraints. 0 3 1 1 0 0    ; gridx: 0 gridy: 3
                             GridBagConstraints/WEST
                             GridBagConstraints/NONE
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
      (.add depart-text-field
        (GridBagConstraints. 1 3 1 1 0 0    ; gridx: 1 gridy: 3
                             GridBagConstraints/WEST
                             GridBagConstraints/HORIZONTAL
                             (Insets. 1 1 1 1) 0 0))
  @param container the java.awt.Container to fill
  @param args the components and GridBagContraints speicifcations
  @returns the filled Container"
  (let [global-defaults
        {:gridwidth 1
         :gridheight 1
         :weightx 0
         :weighty 0
         :anchor :WEST
         :fill :NONE
         :insets `(Insets. 5 5 5 5)
         :ipadx 0
         :ipady 0}

        [defaults rows]
        (if (map? (first args))
          [(into global-defaults (first args)) (rest args)]
          [global-defaults args])]
    `(doto ~container
      ~@(loop [gridy 0 rows rows ret []]
        (if (seq rows)
          (recur (inc gridy) (rest rows)
            (into ret
              (let [row (first rows)]
                (loop [gridx 0 row row ret []]
                  (if (seq row)
                    (recur (inc gridx) (rest row)
                      (conj ret
                        (let [item
                              (first row)

                              component
                              (first item)

                              constraints
                              (assoc (merge defaults
                                            (apply hash-map (rest item)))
                                :gridx gridx :gridy gridy)

                              constraint-values
                              (map (fn [value]
                                (if (keyword? value)
                                  `(. GridBagConstraints
                                      ~(symbol (name value)))
                                  `~value))
                                (map constraints
                                  [:gridx :gridy :gridwidth :gridheight
                                   :weightx :weighty :anchor :fill
                                   :insets :ipadx :ipady]))]
                          `(.add ~component (new GridBagConstraints
                                                 ~@constraint-values)))))
                    ret)))))
          ret)))))
```

Thanks to [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy), [user100464](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100464/user100464), and [kotarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198935/kotarak) for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know `GridBagLayout`, but the following should basically work similar to your macro. If you have a component with a `:height` bigger than 1, you have to add `nil` in the column(s) below it to keep the column counter in sync. Say, your `arrive-text-field` would have a height of 2, than you'd have to add a row of `nil` before the `depart-label` row in order to keep the counters correct. It's just a quick hack.

```
(def default-opts
  {:insets   (Insets. 0 0 0 0)
   :width    1
   :height   1
   :weight-x 0.0
   :weight-y 0.0
   :fill     GridBagConstraints/NONE
   :anchor   GridBagConstraints/WEST
   :ipadx    0
   :ipady    0})

(defn grid-bag-constraints
  [x y global-opts opts]
  (let [{:keys [insets width height weight-x weight-h
                fill anchor ipadx ipady]}
        (merge default-opts global-opts opts)]
    (GridBagConstraints. x y width height weight-x weight-h
                         anchor fill insets ipadx ipady)))

(defn grid-bag-container
  [panel global-opts & rows]
  (doseq [[row-idx row] (map-indexed identity rows)
          [col-idx [target & {:as opts}]] (map-indexed identity row)
          :when target]
    (let [constraints (grid-bag-constraints col-idx row-idx global-opts opts)]
      (.add panel target constraints))))
```

Usage just as before.